# When should math be upright?

Tags: math-mode, formatting

Is there any standards for when math is supposed to be upright?

E.g.

The `f` in `f(x)` is in italics but `cos` in `\cos x` is upright. As I see it, both are functions?

`\int f(x) \, dx` OR `\int f(x) \, mathrm{d}x`?

`P(Y=y)` OR `\text{P}(Y=y)` OR `p(Y=y)` OR `\text{p}(Y=y)` for probabilities?

Comment: Some cases are guideline-dependent, for example the 'd' in 'dx' is upright following ISO, but italic following the traditions of pure maths typography.

Comment: related question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33120/should-subscripts-in-math-mode-be-upright

Comment: The difference between `f` and `cos` is the same as the difference between `x` and `1`; the former is a placeholder for an unspecified object (function or number), whereas the latter is a specific example.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Look at the guidelines for mathematical journals for advice. For example, the [AMS guidelines](https://www.ams.org/publications/authors/AMS-StyleGuide-online.pdf) and [APS guidelines](http://forms.aps.org/author/styleguide.pdf).

In general, anything considered an abbreviation (sin for sine etc.) should be upright. In the case of differentials, it matters what *kind* a lot.