# Typeset subscript material automatically in upright font shape

Tags: math-mode, lyx

As discussed for example here:
[Should subscripts in math mode be upright?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33120/should-subscripts-in-math-mode-be-upright)
subscripts should usually be typeset upright. Is there a possibility to this automatically e.g. inserting something to the document-header? Or, if not possible in LaTeX, is there an option in LyX? Until now I do it like this: `Q _ Alt Z R test` which is quite slow.

Comment: The conclusion you draw is wrong: in `$x_k$`, where the subscript is an index, the “k” should be in italics.

Comment: Agree with @egreg, if the index is say a counting index, then it should be in italics, if on the other hand the index is rather a name, say if `R` is the radius of a lake then one should use `R_{\textup{lake}}` but the counting index refers to a mathematical variable, i.e., italics

Comment: I think for this problem it would be great just to have a package. Maybe one that supports the different syntaxe suggested in the different answers here. My own latex knowledge is to limited to make one. So if someone makes a packages or finds an already existing one, please post it in this thread.

Answer (score 8):

If you have a lot of subscripts, it might be helpful to put the following code in your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
 \begingroup
  \catcode`\_=\active
  \protected\gdef_{\@ifnextchar|\subtextup\sb}
 \endgroup
\def\subtextup|#1|{\sb{\textup{#1}}}
\AtBeginDocument{\catcode`\_=12 \mathcode`\_=32768}
\makeatother
```

Then you can write, say, `$A_|p|$` and get `p` in upright text mode.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
 \begingroup
  \catcode`\_=\active
  \protected\gdef_{\@ifnextchar|\subtextup\sb}
 \endgroup
\def\subtextup|#1|{\sb{\textup{#1}}}
\AtBeginDocument{\catcode`\_=12 \mathcode`\_=32768}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$A_|p|$

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Not sure if that is that easy to use in lyx

Comment: @daleif Okay. (Btw., I actually found the code in your book years ago if I'm not mistaken. `:)`)

Comment: AFAIR Morten made it

Comment: @SvendTveskæg: Is it possible to modify it that it show the same behavior as [Micos](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/303835/21557) lualatex solution? Just replacing the `|#1|` by `{#1}` doesn't seem to work. Also using a gap like `v_ {x,\max}` should typeset as usual (i.e. the `x` italic).

Comment: @SvendTveskæg I posted a follow up question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/661793/automatic-upright-subscripts-in-pdflatex)

Answer (score 6):

Here is TeX based solution.

```
\def\subinrm#1{\sb{\rm#1}}
{\catcode`\_=13 \global\let_=\subinrm}
\mathcode`_="8000
\def\upsubscripts{\catcode`\_=12 } \def\normalsubscripts{\catcode`\_=8 }

\upsubscripts

$A_{lake}$, $\normalsubscripts \sum_{i=1}^\infty {1\over n}$
```

Comment: Could you explain your code?

Answer (score 5):

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution. The solution assumes that subscript material that's encased in curly braces should be rendered in the upright font shape. The main input syntax requirement is that there mustn't be whitespace between the `_` and `{` characters. `$R_{lake}$` works, but `$R_ {lake}$` does not. (Whitespace *inside* the curly braces is OK, though.)

For the convenience of entering single-character subscripts -- a frequently occurring situation! -- it is further assumed that single-character subscripts that are *not* encased in curly braces should *not* be rendered in the upright font shape.

Finally, if there is subscript material which is encased in curly braces but should *not* be rendered with upright letters, you will either need to place the material into math mode explicitly, as is done in the fourth term shown below, or leave a gap between `_` and `{`, as mentioned earlier. I.e., one would have to write `$\sum_ {i=0}^\infty$`.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}   
\usepackage{amsmath,luacode}
\begin{luacode}
```

```lua
function up_subs ( buff )
    return ( string.gsub ( buff , "_(%b{})" , "_{\\textnormal%1}" ) )
end
```

```tex
\end{luacode}
\AtBeginDocument{\directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback(
    "process_input_buffer", up_subs, "up_subs")}}
\begin{document}

$R_t$ $R_{lake}$ $\sum_i$ $\sum_{$i{=}0$}^\infty$ % or: \sum_ {i=0}^\infty

\end{document}
```

Comment: Would it be possible to encapsulate this into a sty file and use it in documents with pdflatex (instead of lualatex)?

Comment: @student - I’m not sure if you’re using the term encapsulation the same way I do. Sticking a code chunk that requires LuaLaTeX into a style file does not make a document that accesses a document that accesses the code chunk via a `\usepackage` directive compiksbke under pdfLaTeX.

Comment: yes that's clear. I should better say: Encapsulate the code and make it accessible to pdflatex such that then (if you want) you could additionally separate it in a sty file.

Comment: @student - I'm not aware of such forms of encapsulation being available to LaTeX documents. I.e., I don't think it's possible to have have the overall compilation of the document being handled by pdfLaTeX while "farming out" some specific operations to LuaLaTeX.

Comment: @student - Just out of curiosity: Is there a constraint that's keeping you from switching from pdfLaTeX to LuaLaTeX to compile your LaTeX documents?

Comment: I am not quite sure, I remember that I already switched some years ago to lualatex, however I got the impression that the compilation is much slower than in pdflatex, see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/261472/lualatex-vs-pdflatex-speed-in-texlive-2015 then I switched back to pdflatex. Today I had to typeset a complex document (wich already slow compilation times) with a lot of upright indices. Then I wished to have a elegant solution for now and for the future of this problem and stumbled over your nice solution.

Comment: At the end I wish to have a package which I could just load (working both with pdflatex or lualtex) to solve the index problem as you suggested. Out of curiosity I wanted to know how your luacode may be made accessible to pdflatex as well.

Comment: You you have an idea for an elegant way to handle mixed cases in your approach, for example v_{x,max}, where x should be italic and max upright?

Comment: @student - How about `$v_ {x,\max}$`? Note the gap between `_` and `{` -- it's essential.

Answer (score 1):

As posted [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/496599/math-mode-subscripts-in-upright-font-by-default), the [answer above by wipet](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/303840/1090) does not work with script classes like `scrartcl`, but can easily be updated to do so:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}

% typesetting indexes upright by default
\def\subinrm#1{\sb{\textnormal{#1}}}
{\catcode`\_=13 \global\let_=\subinrm}
\mathcode`_="8000
\def\upsubscripts{\catcode`\_=12 } \def\normalsubscripts{\catcode`\_=8 }
% the toggle for upright subscripts
\upsubscripts
% the toggle for italic subscripts
%\normalsubscripts

\begin{document}
    $A_{lake}$, $\normalsubscripts \sum_{i=1}^\infty {1\over n}$
\end{document}
```

If you do not need accented characters, such as umlauts, you should use `\mathrm` instead of `\textnormal`, as [David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090/david-carlisle) pointed out. Then, the `amsmath` package is not strictly required either.

Comment: I think this should be posted as a comment to wipet? answer rather than a separate answer.

Comment: I would have preferred that, but I can't comment yet, due to the reputation system.

Comment: In that case, just wait until you have enough reputation. If you are active on this site and make an effort to compose good questions (or answers, when you can), you'll be there in no time.