# Is there a way to make math mode subscripts automatically non-italic?

Tags: math-mode, subscripts

I'm currently working on a report where the majority of subscripts will be non-italic. The way I know how to do this currently is via `\mathrm{}`, which is an absolute horror when you have to do it many times per equation. Any ways around this? I do have the `mtpro2` package, but not sure if there is an option I'm overlooking.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/156641/typeset-index-upright-automatically, is one way. you may get into problems with other packages etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Are the subscript materials you have in mind the names of variables? If so, the variable names should probably be set in upright mode *regardless* of their position relative to the math baseline. However, other subscript material, such as the letters `i` and `t` that serve to index elements of sequences, should probably continue to be set in italics. Thus, an approach that typesets *all* subscript material in upright-roman mode isn't entirely desirable, right?

Fortunately, typesetting all variable names in upright-roman letters can be achieved easily by taking the following two-step approach:

1. Set up a macro named (say) `\V` in the preamble to denote that its argument is a variable name:

   ```
   \usepacakge{amsmath} % loads 'amstext' package, which redefines \textup to be scalable
   \newcommand{\V}[1]{\textup{#1}}
   % Next, define various freqently-used variable names using the \V macro:
   \newcommand\Initial{\V{Initial}}
   \newcommand\Final{\V{Final}}
   ```
2. In the body of the document, you might then write something like

   ```
   \begin{equation}
   F_{\Final} = 3F_{\Initial} + 2F_{\V{Intermediate}}
   \end{equation}
   ```

Note that this approach lets you inform LaTeX on the fly, with a minimum of fuss, that certain strings are variable names.

Another important virtue of this two-step approach is that if you change your mind later on and decide that variable names should be typeset differently -- e.g., in text-italics instead of text-upright roman -- all you'll need to do to accomplish this is to change the definition of the `\V` macro.

Comment: since when is `\textup` defined by `amsmath`, it comes from the kernel :-P

Comment: @Mico: I would use package `amsmath` (or `amstext`) with `\textup`, because the package makes `\textup` scalable as `\text` is working.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek, interesting to know, BTW which part of `amstext` is responsible for that part (normal interest)?

Comment: @daleif: The assignment `\let\nfss@text\text` makes all commands that uses `\nfss@text` scalable.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but what I'd usually do is to have macros defined for the most common "complex" variables: e.g.,
`\newcommand{\GammaD}{\Gamma_{\mathrm{D}}}`.

Answer (score 1):

A semi-answer from personal experience, that I'm sure some people will disagree with - and to my mind more useful than Joce's (who beat me too it while I was writing this):

Define macros for the common stuff, just stick with `_\mathrm{...}` for the rest.
For example if you use `$\lambda_\mathrm{pump}$` and `$\lambda_\mathrm{probe}$` you could define:

```
\newcommand{\wavel}[1]{\lambda_{\mathrm{#1}}}
```

and try:

```
$\wavel{probe}=\wavel{2}$
```

to test - the numbers look fine.  It looks like you can override this by doing `$\wavel{\mathit{i}}$` if you really want - but you're better off not doing that.

**Edit thanks to @tohecz: `{}` inserted around the subscript as `\mathrm{#1}` doesn't provide a group to the subscript without it as I thought it did, and my original is therefore not reliable.**

Comment: Now, if it was possible to tag answers, I would tag this one with [tag:do-not-do-this-please]. It would be better to comply with the LaTeX's syntax at least a bit more, and use `\lambda_{\mathrm{#1}}`

Comment: @tohecz you mean the extra `{}` around the `\mathrm{#1}`? I can add that in, but I'd like to understand why first - does the \mathrm{#1} not already [weak terminology alert] provide a group to the subscripting `_`? Or to put it another way: what's wrong with the syntax given that it works?

Comment: No, it does not provide a group. It's actually a token and a group, so if you think of `_` as of a macro with one argument, `x_\mathrm{y}` is invalid syntax. You're right that it works, which is bceause of how TeX performs the expansion of `_`. It works as long as nobody tweaks `_` to behave in a different way; then it will likely stop working.

Comment: @tohecz, thanks for the explanation, I've edited it in.  looking at my main macro collection I'd usually done it right anyway, just a couple of recent definitions were wrong.

Answer (score 0):

What I usually have in my documents in the preamble is the following line

```
\providecommand{\cind}[1]{_{\textrm{#1}}}
```

With this command I'm completely flexible with the variable name as well as with the index name and I don't have to define something else in the preamble.

Comment: While this definition is fine for variable names in subscript positions, it doesn't work if the variable names need to appear, say, on the baseline or in a superscript position.