# Default setting of non-italic subscripts in mathmode

Tags: math-mode, formatting, subscripts

I want to set all sub-/superscripts in math mode of an existing document in non-italic style. How can I change the commands `^` and `_`, appropriately?

Comment: Duplicate?  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/158872/is-there-a-way-to-make-math-mode-subscripts-automatically-non-italic and this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/156641/typeset-subscript-material-automatically-in-upright-font-shape.  The second question in particular, shows automation techniques.

Comment: As I do not want to change the existing text body, I would like to redefine the aforementioned commands in the preamble. The change should hold for sub-/superscripts with and without curly braces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stealing from and extending (for superscripts)  wipet's answer at cited question, [Typeset subscript material automatically in upright font shape](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/156641/typeset-subscript-material-automatically-in-upright-font-shape)

EDITED to replace `\rm` with `\mathrm{}`, since the `memoir` class (used by the OP) does not support `\rm`.  Of course, this will break the use in plain TeX, which wipet touted.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\def\subinrm#1{\sb{\mathrm{#1}}}
{\catcode`\_=13 \global\let_=\subinrm}
\mathcode`_="8000
\def\supinrm#1{\sp{\mathrm{#1}}}
{\catcode`\^=13 \global\let^=\supinrm}
\mathcode`^="8000
\def\upsubscripts{\catcode`\_=12 } \def\normalsubscripts{\catcode`\_=8 }
\def\upsupscripts{\catcode`\^=12 } \def\normalsupscripts{\catcode`\^=7 }
\begin{document}
\upsubscripts
$A_{lake}  a_x a_x^y$

\upsupscripts
$A_{lake}  a_x a_x^y$

\normalsubscripts\normalsupscripts
$A_{lake}  a_x a_x^y$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. One comment: I use document class memoir. Only the first letter of subscript "lake" in the first and second formulation is typed non-italic. Maybe a conflict of document class?

Comment: @Mathias With `memoir`, I get `\rm` not supported in math mode error.

Comment: @Mathias Please see my revision.

Comment: In memoir following is necessary:
\renewcommand{\sl}{\textsl}
\renewcommand{\rm}{\textrm}

Comment: @Mathias I think one wants `\mathrm` rather than `\textrm`.  That way, the supscripts can contain, for example, `\cos` and `\alpha`, etc..

Comment: I figured out that the solution works fine unless the subscript contains a Greek letter such as \theta. Can you imagine why?

Comment: @Mathias My solution works with `\theta` in the subscript.  It won't work *if* you use your `\textrm` instead of `\mathrm`.

Comment: The rm's were not the trouble makers. The upright Greek letters are another building site of usepackage newtxmath that I use. Thanks.

Comment: @Mathias Oh, you are hoping to also have upright Greek?  If you are using pdflatex, you might consider this answer as a possibility: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145926/upright-greek-font-fitting-to-computer-modern/230220#230220