# Is there a way to automate a switch into text mode after a _

Tags: math-mode, subscripts, text-mode

I am a physics student and we have been told that indices that *abbreviate* some descriptive word or indices that are just to *distinguish* between say different objects like the mass of two objects `A` and `B` *shouldn't be in italics* in an equation. An example for that would be `$m_\text{tot} = m_\text{A} + m_\text{B}$`.
For *physical constants*, or any non made up index for that matter, the indices *should be in italics* as the rest of the equation. Here an example would be the mass of an electron `$m_e$`.

Since basically **every** index is for things you make up, for almost every index I have to write out `_\text{...}`. This just clutters my equations so much that I tried to find a way to automate a switch into text mode after a `_` character, but found nothing. So here I am asking you people: Do you know a way?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

EDIT: See also [Is there a way to make math mode subscripts automatically non-italic?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/158872/is-there-a-way-to-make-math-mode-subscripts-automatically-non-italic?rq=1)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: note that you should not use `\text` otherwise you will get the current font from before the math, eg italic in theorems. use `m_{\mathrm{tot}}`

Comment: I would not redefine the math primitives, although that is possible just do `\newcommand\z[1]{_{\mathrm{#1}}`  then you can use `m\z{tot}` which is only one character more than `m_{tot}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might use a different character to introduce textual subscripts, so you can keep `_` to do its usual job.

I chose `?` because it's unlikely to show up in math formulas.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\textualsubscript}[1]{%
  _{\textnormal{\upshape#1}}%
}
\begingroup\lccode`~=`? \lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\textualsubscript
\AtBeginDocument{\mathcode`?="8000 }

\begin{document}

$m?{tot}=m?{A}+m?{B}-m_{e}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

With a slightly different approach we can allow for nested subscripts (of course `?` can never appear in such places).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \l__egreg_textualsb_arg_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \egreg_textualsb:n
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l__egreg_textualsb_arg_tl { #1 }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l__egreg_textualsb_arg_tl { ? } { \__egreg_textualsb:n }
  \__egreg_textualsb:V \l__egreg_textualsb_arg_tl
 }
\char_set_active_eq:nN { `? } \egreg_textualsb:n

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__egreg_textualsb:n
 {
  \ensuremath{\sb{\textnormal{\upshape#1}}}%
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__egreg_textualsb:n { V }

\AtBeginDocument
 {
  \char_set_mathcode:nn { `? } { "8000 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$m?{tot}=m?{A?{téxt}}+m?{B}-m_{e}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. Since I'm new to LaTeX I don't know a lot about the things you can customize, but I'm eager to learn. Would you care to briefly explain what your code does?

Comment: @Luguza This has been explained elsewhere in the site. Basically, ``\mathcode`@="8000`` tells TeX to treat `?` as a command `\let` equal to the one introduced beforehand with a known trick. Look for “math active”.

Comment: This works great for only one subscript, but with multiple levels of subscripts it doesn't work, for example:
\begin{equation}
    A?{B?C}
\end{equation} 
will just give me A subscripted with the text "B?C", not A subscripted with B subscripted with C. 

Could you edit your answer to also allow for this?

Comment: @Luguza Added as requested

Comment: You might want to add a command `\?` which prints the original question mark.

Comment: Anyway, I think this “nested subscripts” business goes against the original logic of the syntax. The idea was that `_` meant math mode subscript while `?` meant text mode subscript. So `m?{A?{téxt}}` should really be `m_{A?{téxt}}`.

Answer (score 2):

If you're willing and able to use LuaLaTeX to compile your document, the following solution may be of interest to you. The solution defines a Lua function, called `sub2mathrm`, which encases subscript terms in `\mathrm` wrappers if there is *no whitespace* between the `_` (underscore) character and (a) material encased in curly braces -- e.g., `{tot}` -- or (b) a single alphabetic character -- e.g., `A` or `B`. Conversely, if there *is* some whitespace after the `_` character, the Lua function does nothing. The Lua function does nothing with `A_\sigma` either, since the backslash character in `\sigma` is not an alphabetical character. `sub2mathrm` performs its work with the help of Lua's powerful `string.gsub` ("generalized substitution") function.

The Lua function is activated by executing `\SubToMathrmOn`, a utility macro that assigns `sub2mathrm` to the LuaTeX `process_input_buffer` callback. It is deactivated by running the utility macro `\SubToMathrmOn`.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode} % for 'luacode' environment
\begin{luacode}
```

```lua
  function sub2mathrm ( s )
    s = s:gsub ( "_(%b{})" , "_{\\mathrm%1}" )
    s = s:gsub ( "_(%a)" , "_{\\mathrm{%1}}" )
    return s
  end
```

```tex
\end{luacode}

%% define two utility macros:
\newcommand\SubToMathrmOn{\directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback ( 
   "process_input_buffer" , sub2mathrm , "sub2mathrm" )}}
\newcommand\SubToMathrmOff{\directlua{luatexbase.remove_from_callback ( 
   "process_input_buffer" , "sub2mathrm" )}}

\begin{document}
\SubToMathrmOn % Activate the Lua function

$m_{tot} = m_A + m_B$     % no whitespace after "_"

$m_ {tot} = m _ A + m_ B$ % whitespace after "_"

\SubToMathrmOff % Deactivate the Lua function

$m_{tot} = m_A + m_B$

\end{document}
```

Comment: It's really elegant, but I'm working in overleaf and I don't think I can use LuaLaTeX there.

Comment: @Luguza - Not true. There's a pull-down menu from which you can choose pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX, or LuaLaTeX.