# How can I use \csname and \endcsname in the argument of \urldef?

Tags: hyperref, urls, endnotes, url, enotez

[Donald Arsenau's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/208556/donald-arseneau) [url](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/url) package provides the macro `\urldef`, which is very handy when one needs to typeset a URL string in a footnote or endnote. For instance,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}     % for \url and \urldef commands
\usepackage{enotez}  % for \endnote and \printendnotes commands
\setenotez{backref = true}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,urlcolor=blue}

\begin{document}
\urldef{\basicurl}\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions}
blabla\endnote{\basicurl}

\clearpage
\printendnotes
\end{document}
```

generates

[image]

on the endnotes page, where the red numeral `1` is a back-reference to the location in the main document where the `\endnote` command occurred.

So far, so good. Is there a way to generalize this setup by replacing the hard-coded macro name `\basicurl` with, say, `\csname zz\themycounter\endcsname`?

Here, `\themycounter` is the arabic-numeral expression of the value of a counter variable name named `mycounter`. (By way of background: The document will eventually hold *many* endnotes, each with one URL string, and it's not feasible to define a new `\basicurl` directive before each and every `\endnote` command. I'm trying to make the argument of `\urldef` unique, in order to play nice with the [enotez](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/enotez) package. For more background information, please see [this query](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/594302/5001).)

I naively tried

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{mycounter}
\usepackage{url}     % for \url and \urldef commands
\usepackage{enotez}  % for \endnote and \printendnotes commands
\setenotez{backref = true}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,urlcolor=blue}

\begin{document}
\stepcounter{mycounter}
\urldef{\csname zz\themycounter\endcsname}\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions}
blabla\endnote{\csname zz\themycounter\endcsname}
\clearpage
\printendnotes
\end{document}
```

But this generates the following error message:

```
! Extra \endcsname.
\declare@robustcommand ...e \string #1 \endcsname

l.11 ...url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions}
```

Am I doing something wrong, or can `\urldef` truly not handle `\csname ... \endcsname`-type macro commands?

---

**Addendum**, posted upon receiving @JairoA.delRio' suggestion to replace

```
\urldef{\csname zz\themycounter\endcsname}\url{...}
```

with

```
\expandafter\urldef\expandafter{\csname zz\themycounter\endcsname}\url{...}
```

This modification definitely solves the problem mentioned above. However, it leads to another problem, best illustrated by the following, expanded (pun intended) MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{mycounter}
\usepackage{url}     % for \url and \urldef commands
\usepackage{enotez}  % for \endnote and \printendnotes commands
\setenotez{backref = true}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,urlcolor=blue}

\begin{document}

\stepcounter{mycounter}
\expandafter\urldef\expandafter{\csname zz\themycounter\endcsname}\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions}
blabla\endnote{\csname zz\themycounter\endcsname}

\stepcounter{mycounter}
\expandafter\urldef\expandafter{\csname zz\themycounter\endcsname}\url{https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0304405X00000763}
more blabla\endnote{\csname zz\themycounter\endcsname}

\clearpage
\printendnotes
\end{document}
```

This is basically the same as before -- except for the additional set of `\stepcounter{mycounter}`, `\urldef`, and `\endnote` directives. Unhappily, the endnotes page now consists of the following:

[image]

Oberve that the same URL string is shown twice even though the two instances of `\endnote` use the equivalent of `\zz1` and `\zz2`, respectively.

**Updated question**: Is there something else about my code that's not quite right, or have I maybe come across a bug in the [enotez](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/enotez) package?

Comment: `\expandafter\urldef\expandafter{\csname zz\themycounter\endcsname}\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions}`?

Comment: @JairoA.delRio - Many thanks for this suggestion! It definitely solves one problem, but another one remains. I will post an addendum to the query to illustrate what happens to the endnotes when this setup is employed twice.

Comment: It would be better to update the question such that it would appear as if it was written right now (the historical information is in the revision history). (It is probably not a [chameleon question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478).)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `\endnote{\csname zz\themycounter\endcsname}`, the text stored in the endnote will have `\themycounter` and so the value current at the time `\printendnotes` will be used.

You have to build the control sequence name *before* `\endnote` starts its job. But there's a catch! There's always a catch, you know…

Due to how `enotez` processes the token lists it's fed with, `\zz2` (resulting from your `\urldef`, will be treated separately (this is because the thing is stored in the `.aux` file) as if it were `\zz` followed by `2`.

How to fix? Use Roman numerals instead of Arabic ones.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}     % for \url and \urldef commands
\usepackage{enotez}  % for \endnote and \printendnotes commands
\usepackage{hyperref}

\setenotez{backref = true}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,urlcolor=blue}

\newcounter{mycounter}
\renewcommand{\themycounter}{\romannumeral\value{mycounter}}

\begin{document}

\stepcounter{mycounter}
\expandafter\urldef\csname zz\themycounter\endcsname
  \url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions}

blabla\expandafter\endnote\expandafter{\csname zz\themycounter\endcsname}

\stepcounter{mycounter}

\expandafter\urldef\csname zz\themycounter\endcsname
  \url{https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0304405X00000763}

more blabla\expandafter\endnote\expandafter{\csname zz\themycounter\endcsname}

\clearpage
\printendnotes

\end{document}
```

Why not

```
\renewcommand{\themycounter}{\roman{mycounter}}
```

instead of using the primitive `\romannumeral`? Because some `babel` modules redefine `\roman` in a way that would conflict with this job.

[image]

We can define a macro for this kind of endnotes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}     % for \url and \urldef commands
\usepackage{enotez}  % for \endnote and \printendnotes commands
\usepackage{hyperref}

\setenotez{backref = true}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,urlcolor=blue}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\endnoteurl}{v}
 {
  \int_incr:N \__mico_endnoteurl_int
  \exp_args:Nc \urldef { zz \int_to_roman:n { \__mico_endnoteurl_int } } \url{#1}
  \exp_args:Ne \endnote
   { \exp_not:c { zz \int_to_roman:n { \__mico_endnoteurl_int } } }
 }
\int_new:N \__mico_endnoteurl_int
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

blabla\endnoteurl{https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions}

more blabla\endnoteurl{https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0304405X00000763}

\clearpage
\printendnotes

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is an expansion problem. The first issue has been discussed by [Jairo A. del Rio](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/226564/jairo-a-del-rio) in the comments: You need to expand `\csname <string>\endcsname` before `\urldef` tries to use it. So

```
\expandafter\urldef\expandafter{\csname zz\themycounter\endcsname}
  \url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions}
```

works.

This is because `\urldef` behaves pretty much like `\def` here. With

```
\def\csname zz\themycounter\endcsname{Hullo}
```

you redefine `\csname`. But with

```
\expandafter\def\csname zz\themycounter\endcsname{Hullo}
```

you actually redefine `\zz<expansion of \themycounter>`.

A similar thing holds for `\endnote`, but there we additionally need to take into account that `\endnote` writes the contents of the endnote to an external file (which needs care in terms of expansion).

`\endnote` tries to write its argument as is without expansion. You'll want `\endnote` to write `\csname zz<expansion of \themycounter>\endcsname` to the file, not `\csname zz\themycounter\endcsname` or anything else (in particular we also don't want `\zz1`, we need `\csname zz1\endcsname`).

I gave up trying to figure out the optimal number of expansions here (it's three in this case) and just went for a full `\edef` expansion with the old `\begingroup \edef...{\endgroup}` trick ([Explanations about \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/61223/35864)). (This is safe as long as `\themycounter` is expandable, which you already assume when you say `\csname zz\themycounter\endcsname`).

Both of these things are probably easiest done with a helper definition.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{enotez}
\setenotez{backref = true}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,urlcolor=blue}

\newcounter{mycounter}

\newcommand*\zzurldef{\zzurldednr{\themycounter}}
\newcommand*\zzurldednr[1]{\expandafter\urldef\expandafter{\csname zz#1\endcsname}}

\newcommand*\zzendnote{%
  \begingroup
  \edef\temp{\endgroup
    \noexpand\zzendnotenr{\themycounter}}%
  \temp}
\newcommand*\zzendnotenr[1]{\endnote{\csname zz#1\endcsname}}


\begin{document}
\stepcounter{mycounter}
\zzurldef\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions}
blabla\zzendnote

\stepcounter{mycounter}
\zzurldef\url{https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0304405X00000763}
more blabla\zzendnote

\printendnotes
\end{document}
```

[image: Notes//1. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions//2. https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0304405X00000763]

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, which works just fine. In the end, though, I chose to award the check-mark to @egreg's answer, as I find its code to be every so slightly more elegant.