# Is there a package which does typeset subscripts automatically upright or provides an easy syntax to do to so?

Tags: math-mode, packages

Some time ago there was a question of how to typeset subscripts automatically upright ([Typeset subscript material automatically in upright font shape](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/156641/typeset-index-upright-automatically)). The answer works, but it seems like a hack.

Is there any package out there which solves this problem just by loading the package? I.e. a package which does typeset subscripts automatically upright or provides an easy syntax to do to so?

Comment: If you want every subscript in the document, `A_a` and `A_{abc}` for instance, to be upright, just remove the verticals bar in that hack, converting `|#1|` into `#1`.

Comment: @Manuel: Thanks, I know this. My point is more about if there is a package which handels this problem and it's variants. I don't want to add this hack every time to my document. Sure I can include it as a file, but maybe there is a published package for this. That's what I want to know.

Comment: There is nothing stopping you from copying that hack into your own style fine, call it `upsubs.sty`.  Just start with `\ProvidesPackage{upsubs} [2016/04/12 V1.0]`, insert the hack, and end with `\endinput`.  Voila!  Now you have it in a package.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes See my previous comment, clearly I can also make a sty file; I just want to know if there there are **published** packages that deal with that problem, at best something included in texlive. Please don't tell me that I could publish one. Yes, maybe I am going to to this if it turns out that there isn't a package up to now...

Answer (score 1):

As far as I have looked, there are no packages that offer this feature up to now. Only "hacks" as the answer linked by the OP.