# How to typeset upright ħ?

Tags: math-mode, formatting, italic

As described in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33122/51512), constants should be typeset upright, not in italics. However the symbol for reduced Planck's constant ([image: ħ], `\hbar`) is in italics by default. This is especially obvious when using both `h` and `\hbar` in one equation. How do I make LaTeX typeset ħ upright?

[image: ħ = h/2π]

---

**EDIT:** I've tried `\mathrm`, `\text`, `\textup`, none of them works.

Comment: Opinions on the subject tend to differ but the bit about upright constants usually refer to _math_ constants. _Physical_ constants are usually written italic. I have never seen upright c, h and whatnot. (Theoretical physicist talking here.)

Comment: In fact, I'm pretty sure ISO norms dictate (for whatever reason) upright for mathematical and italics for physical constants. In my experience, most mathematicians do not see the point of this distinction but many physicists abide by it. (Including myself.)

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's somewhere in “ISO 80000-1:2009”. Or maybe “-3” or “-7”. But I'm not sure it really matters, as each of these PDFs are sold at $160 ‍♂️️. But if you find a way to access those, I'll gladly read them.

Comment: Have you tried `\mathrm{\hbar}`?

Comment: \usepackage{tipa}
\textcrh

Comment: BTW, `\hbar` is not a true constant, because it's only known up to a certain precision, so it actually changes each time the measurements get better.

Comment: @HenriMenke Not since May 2019 any more `:-)`

Comment: In Unicode, in the Letterlike Symbols code block, letters like ℋ  ℌ ℍ ℎ ℏ  are *defined* as script, fraktur, double-struck, italic, etc.

Comment: @Nico just adding `\usepackage{tipa}` breaks my document. @Cicada “ℏ” may be defined as italic in Unicode, that doesn't mean there isn't also a “ħ” symbol.

Comment: @campa I remember that the “rationale” for typesetting physical constants in italic type was that their value is bound to change because of better measurements. Of course now this is absurd (it was to begin with, actually), because the speed of light and the Planck constant are defined as ***exact*** values.

Comment: @m93a What tex-distribution and documentclass are you using? You can have a look at the [package manual](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tipa)  on p.14 "Crossed H". I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: @m93a Make sure that you include \usepackage{tipa} after \documentclass and before \begin{document} e.g. 
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tipa}
\begin{document}
\textcrh
\end{document}

Comment: @Nico In empty document this works fine, but as soon as I add it to the document where I needed ħ, just adding `\usepackage{tipa}` breaks several existing equations and `xelatex` refuses to build the document. The equations fail with: `Font shape \`T3/lmr/m/n' undefined
(Font) using \`T3/cmr/m/n' instead.` and several other errors.

Comment: It's unclear why anyone should think "constants should be typeset upright". Also for dimensionless, non-changing constants like Bernoilli numbers or the number pi, or for the infinitesimals dx or dy in an integral this simply isn't what people normally do.
Only numerals are usually upright, and abbreviated names when used as subscript or superscript.

Comment: @JosBergervoet This is not the correct place to discuss this. Use the link provided in my question and find out / express your concern there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I won't delve into the issue whether this should be done or not.

The LaTeX kernel defines

```
\def\hbar{{\mathchar'26\mkern-9muh}}
```

and as such `\mathrm{\hbar}` should give an upright `\hbar`. However, the negative space of 9 math units is a wee bit too much for the upright letter; `8mu` looks better, so you can use

```
\renewcommand*{\hbar}{{\mkern-1mu\mathchar'26\mkern-8mu\mathrm{h}}}
```

Care should be taken when font packages are loaded, for many of them contain `\hbar` as symbol. Obvious example: `amssymb`. In this case the redefinition of `\hbar` bust be issued *after* loading any font packages. To be on the safe side the above redefinition could be put into a `\AtBeginDocument` hook

```
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand*{\hbar}{{\mkern-1mu\mathchar'26\mkern-8mu\mathrm{h}}}}
```

**EDIT** To lower the bar a little the safest way is IMO to put it into a box and lower it by an amount relative to the height of the box.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand*{\hbar}{{\mkern-1mu\mathchar'26\mkern-8mu\mathrm{h}}}
$\hbar \scriptstyle\hbar \scriptscriptstyle\hbar$

\renewcommand*{\hbar}{{\mathpalette\hbaraux\relax\mathrm{h}}}
\newcommand*{\hbaraux}[2]{\sbox0{\mathsurround=0pt$#1\mathchar'26$}\mkern-1mu\lower.07\ht0\box0\mkern-8mu}
$\hbar \scriptstyle\hbar \scriptscriptstyle\hbar$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try it in context? You need `\mkern-1mu` in front of `\mathchar`. The total amount of backspacing should be 9mu, because that's the width of the bar.

Comment: @egreg Yes, I did; apparently in my typical use cases no big difference did show up. But of course you are right...

Comment: The difference is subtle, but noticeable: in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eeh6M.png) the top has a simple h, the middle the `\hbar` without the `\mkern-1mu` and the bottom the fixed symbol.

Comment: I found that in subscripts and superscripts, this macro fails. Doing `$A^\hbar$` is enough to reproduce the issue. I have no idea why, though, as the original `\hbar` works fine…

Comment: @m93a I've just tried it and it works without problems for me. How does the macro fail?

Comment: Oh my bad. I edited the code to make the bar appear lower and than forgot about it. Your code works great. This is quite embarrassing, sorry to waste your time ️. In my code I used [`\raisebox`](https://www.overleaf.com/read/yzqvgrnkwgmc) which didn't work properly in the superscript. Do you have any idea how to lower the bar without breaking the superscripts? Thanks! :)

Comment: @m93a See edit.