# How can I get an upright \hbar using unicode-math?

Tags: math-mode, unicode, unicode-math, math-fonts

I would like to have an upright `\hbar` glyph in my documents and I'm using `unicode-math`. The example in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/527104/218142 doesn't seem to work when I load `unicode-math`. The bar obviously moves relative to the `h`.  Why does this happen, and how can I get the upright `\hbar` when loading `unicode-math`?

My MWE:

```
% !TEX program = lualatexmk
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand*{\hbar}{{\mathpalette\hbaraux\relax\symup{h}}}
\newcommand*{\hbaraux}[2]{\sbox0{\mathsurround=0pt$#1\mathchar"AF$}\mkern-1mu\lower.07\ht0\box0\mkern-8mu}

\( \hbar \scriptstyle\hbar \scriptscriptstyle\hbar \)
\end{document}
```

This MWE produces the following output:

[image: MWE output showing the bar doesn't stay put relative to the h]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need to construct things by hand, you want U+0127 ħ

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand*{\hbar}{\mathrm{^^^^0127}}

 \( \hbar \scriptstyle\hbar \scriptscriptstyle\hbar \)
\end{document}
```

Comment: Blindingly simple.

Comment: It doesn't work if I change `\mathrm` to `\symup`. Why is that?

Comment: the latin modern math font hasn't got a glyph in slot 0127 you need to get it from the text font. @LaTeXereXeTaL

Answer (score 3):

You can compose the character, but you have to do it the proper way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \DeclareRobustCommand{\hbar}{{\mathpalette\hbar@\relax\symup{h}}}%
}
\newcommand*{\hbar@}[2]{%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\raisebox{-0.07\height}{$\m@th#1\mkern-1mu\mathchar"AF$}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\( \hbar \scriptstyle\hbar \scriptscriptstyle\hbar \)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The box issue was confusing me. I still do not entirely understand it and need to study it more. I have never seen `\m@th` before. Where is it documented?

Comment: @LaTeXereXeTaL `\m@th` is shorthand for `\mathsurround=0pt`. The idea here is to make a zero width box that protrudes left 1mu.