# Can this code be more compact?

Tags: xparse, grouping

I have a number of commands with the same structure as this one and I'm wondering whether or not the code can be compacted to avoid having to type the `E_{K` and `K_{\symup{trans}` twice each. I don't see a way to do it without creating problems with breaking the grouping.

My MWE:

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatexmk
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass{article}
% xparse is now automatically loaded

\NewDocumentCommand{\translationalkineticenergy}{ s d[] }{%
  % d[] must be used because of the way consecutive optional
  %  arguments are handled. See xparse docs for details.
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}%
  {% We have a *.
    \IfValueTF{#2}%
    {% 
      E_{K{\symup{,}#2}}%
    }%
    {% 
      E_{K}%
    }%
  }%
  {% We don't have a *.
    \IfValueTF{#2}%
    {% 
      K_{\symup{trans}{\textnormal{,}#2}}%
    }%
    {% 
      K_{\symup{trans}}%
    }%
  }%
}%

\begin{document}

\( \translationalkineticenergy \quad \translationalkineticenergy[\symup{final}] 
   \quad \translationalkineticenergy* \quad \translationalkineticenergy*[\symup{final}]  \) 

\end{document}
```

**UPDATE:** While I was waiting I got it down to this new MWE.

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatexmk
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass{article}
% xparse is now automatically loaded

\NewDocumentCommand{\translationalkineticenergy}{ s d[] }{%
  % d[] must be used because of the way consecutive optional
  %  arguments are handled. See xparse docs for details.
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}%
  {% We have a *.
    E_{K{\IfValueT{#2}{\symup{,}#2}}}
  }%
  {% We don't have a *.
    K_{\symup{trans}\IfValueT{#2}{\symup{,}#2}}
  }%
}%

\begin{document}

\( \translationalkineticenergy \quad \translationalkineticenergy[\symup{final}] 
   \quad \translationalkineticenergy* \quad \translationalkineticenergy*[\symup{final}]  \) 

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\mathrm` would be better (and a lot more efficient) than `\textnormal`

Comment: It's just a placeholder for now. I'm using `unicode-math` so I will likely use `\symup`. However, https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/362512/218142 has influenced me.

Comment: that's comparing three `\text...` commands but `\math...` or `\symb...` are usually more suitable.

Comment: Okay. I just want to ensure the labels are safe from changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two simplifications possible here.  First is in

```latex
    \IfValueTF{#2}%
    {% 
      E_{K{\textnormal{,}#2}}%
    }%
    {% 
      E_{K}%
    }%
```

The difference between the two branches is that for `true` you have an extra `{\textnormal{,}#2}`, you can put the test inside the subscript:

```latex
      E_{K%
         \IfValueT{#2}{\textnormal{,}#2}%
        }%
```

The second one is a bit trickier.  You see, after TeX sees a subscript (or superscript) token, the `{` doesn't have to be an explicit brace: it can be an implicit one, and implicit braces don't count for brace-balancing.  Both these do the same:

```latex
a_{bc}
a_\bgroup bc\egroup
```

so you can do that in your macro:

```latex
\NewDocumentCommand{\translationalkineticenergy}{ s d[] }{%
  % d[] must be used because of the way consecutive optional
  %  arguments are handled. See xparse docs for details.
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}%
    {E_\bgroup K}% We have a *.
    {K_\bgroup \textnormal{trans}}% We don't have a *.
         \IfValueT{#2}{\textnormal{,}#2}%
       \egroup
  }%
```

note that you have two `\bgroup` in there, but only one `\egroup`, and that's fine because  only one of the two `\bgroup` will be actually seen.

Comment: I see I was on the right track! I think `\bgroup` and `\egroup` were what I was looking for.